# How to get unwind segue without animation?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am new to iOS app developing.

I want an unwind segue without any animation, but I don't know how to get that. Could anybody help me out???

Thanks a lot!!

Comment: read this article http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/10/25/ios-unwind-segues/

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to remove the last viewController displayed from your navigation stack you can use `[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated: NO];`

Comment: I tried unchecking animated on an exit segue but did not get the desired effect, at least on a device running 9.1. This worked fine for me, though it bypasses the segue mechanism including prepareForSegue and the "landing selector" so if you need additional magic you'll have to do more.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should perform custom animation for unwind segue.
and don't animate your VC in that animation.

Try this to perform Unwind segue with animation: http://spin.atomicobject.com/2015/03/03/ios-unwind-segue-custom-animation/

Answer (score 0):

I'm searching for an answer to this as well. The one thing I do know, which hasn't been mentioned yet, is that in Xcode 7 there's a new box you can uncheck.

Go to the storyboard and select the unwind segue. In the inspector you where the ID and class are, below the text fields there's now a checkbox which says "Animates". You can uncheck it, telling it not to animate the unwind.

Too easy, right? Yup. The catch is that it's new and only works for iOS9. If you're targeting anything earlier, you need a different solution.